# sql server stored proc, can't get result set back in java

Tags: java, sql-server, resultset, callable-statement

I have created a stored proc in a sql server db that appears to be executing  properly for one record. The code is shown below:

```
try {
                String className="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";
                String username="username";
                String url="jdbc:sqlserver://someDB:8808;SelectMethod=cursor";
                String password="password";
                Class.forName(className);
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);




                // need to obtain store procedure in db(a sql script stored in our sql server db)
                CallableStatement cstmt = conn.prepareCall("{call dbo.sp_SomeProc(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}");
                cstmt.setString (1,"id34234, id34246, id234234");
                cstmt.registerOutParameter(2, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
                cstmt.registerOutParameter(3, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
                cstmt.registerOutParameter(4, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
                cstmt.registerOutParameter(5, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
                cstmt.registerOutParameter(6, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
                cstmt.registerOutParameter(7, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
                cstmt.registerOutParameter(8, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
                cstmt.registerOutParameter(9, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);




               int rowsAffected = 0;
               boolean isResults = cstmt.execute();
               while(isResults  || rowsAffected != -1) {
                     if(isResults) {
                         rs = cstmt.getResultSet();
                         break;
                     }else {
                          rowsAffected = cstmt.getUpdateCount();
                     }
                     isResults = cstmt.getMoreResults();
               }
            while(rs.next()) {
               slInfo.add(cstmt.getString(2));
               slInfo.add(cstmt.getString(3));
               slInfo.add(cstmt.getString(4));
               slInfo.add(cstmt.getString(5));
               slInfo.add(cstmt.getString(6));
               slInfo.add(cstmt.getString(7));
               slInfo.add(cstmt.getString(8));
               slInfo.add(cstmt.getString(9));
             }


                writeToFile(outFileName, slInfo);

            }catch(SQLException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();

            }catch(ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }finally {
                try { cstmt.close(); } catch (Exception e) { /* ignored */ }
                try { conn.close(); } catch (Exception e) { /* ignored */ }
            }
```

The issue is since I have more than one record, I need to obtain a result set. However, every attempt other than `executeUpdate()` results in an exception.

My first attempt:

`ResultSet rs = cstmt.executeQuery() // instead cstmt.executeUpdate()`
the exception:
`com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The statement did not return a result set.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:171)`

Second attempt:

```
 cstmt.execute();
 ResultSet rs = (ResultSet)cstmt.getObject(1) // not actually sure what index to use here
```

It appears that the first attempt is what I have seen other people do, but I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. Any help would be most appreciated.

**UPDATE**
Here is the stored proc:

```
USE [someDB]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_GetAvatarInfo] 
(
@idList VARCHAR(MAX), 
@uniqueIdent VARCHAR(64) OUTPUT,
@FULLNAME VARCHAR(128) OUTPUT, 
@CCNUMSEQ VARCHAR(64) OUTPUT, 
@ALIASTYPE VARCHAR(64) OUTPUT,
@SLNUMBER VARCHAR(64) OUTPUT,
@TISSUETYPE VARCHAR(64) OUTPUT,
@SAMPLESUBTYPE VARCHAR(64) OUTPUT,
@SUBMITTEDDIAG VARCHAR(64) OUTPUT
)
AS 
BEGIN 

DECLARE @idAvatarEvent INT,
        @avatarDisease INT;

SELECT @idAvatarEvent = idEventType
        FROM CCR.dbo.EventType
WHERE codeCancerGroup = 'TCC' AND eventType = 'Avatar';

--Create table to hold all SL ids that are involved in the search
IF (OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#SLList') IS NOT NULL) DROP TABLE #SLList;
CREATE TABLE #SLList
(
        idAlias INT NOT NULL IDENTITY (1,1)
        ,SLNumber VARCHar(100)
)


INSERT INTO #SLList (SLNumber)
SELECT [str]
FROM BST.dbo.fn_parseString(@idList, ',');

SELECT @avatarDisease = ATT.idAttribute
        FROM CCR.dbo.Attribute          ATT
          JOIN CCR.dbo.AttributeContainer ATC ON ATT.idAttributeContainer = ATC.idAttributeContainer
WHERE ATT.attributeName = 'avatarDiseaseGroup'
        AND ATC.containerName = 'Avatar'

  SELECT @PERMRN = per.mrn,
         @FULLNAME = per.firstName + ' ' + per.lastName,
         @CCNUMSEQ = ali.ccNumberSeq, 
         @ALIASTYPE = sat.aliasType, 
         @SLNUMBER = sl.SLNumber, 
         @TISSUETYPE = sst.description,
         @SAMPLESUBTYPE = case when pt.preparationType LIKE '%Formalin%' THEN 'FFPE' ELSE pt.preparationType END,
         @SUBMITTEDDIAG = ac.choice
        FROM #SLList sl
                LEFT JOIN DB1.dbo.AliquotAlias sa on sl.SLNumber = sa.alias
                LEFT JOIN DB1.dbo.AliquotAliasType sat on sa.idAliasType = sat.idAliasType
                LEFT JOIN DB1.dbo.VIEW_Aliquot2 ali on sa.idAliquot = ali.idAliquot
                LEFT JOIN DB1.dbo.Sample sam on ali.idSample = sam.id
                LEFT JOIN DB1.dbo.VIEW_SampleSubType sst on sam.codeSampleSubType = sst.codeSampleSubType
                LEFT JOIN DB1.dbo.PreparationType pt on sam.idPreparationType = pt.id
                LEFT JOIN DB1.dbo.BSTCollection col on sam.idBSTCollection = col.idBSTCollection
                LEFT JOIN DB1.dbo.BSTPatient pat on col.idBSTPatient = pat.idBSTPatient
                LEFT JOIN DB2.dbo.Person per on pat.idPerson = per.idPerson
                LEFT JOIN DB3.dbo.Patient cpat on per.idPerson = cpat.idPerson
                LEFT JOIN DB3.dbo.PatientCancerGroup pcg on cpat.idPatient = pcg.idPatient AND pcg.codeCancerGroup = 'TCC'
                LEFT JOIN DB3.dbo.MedicalEvent med on pcg.idPatient = med.idPatient AND pcg.codeCancerGroup = med.codeCancerGroup AND med.idEventType = @idAvatarEvent
                LEFT JOIN DB3.dbo.AttributeValue av on med.idAttributeValueSet = av.idAttributeValueSet AND av.idAttribute = @avatarDisease
                LEFT JOIN DB3.dbo.AttributeChoice ac on av.valueIdAttributeChoice = ac.idAttributeChoice
        ORDER BY MRN
END;
```

Comment: https://programmaticponderings.com/2012/08/24/calling-sql-server-stored-procedures-with-java-using-jdbc/

Comment: I actually read this article, I tried getting the result set like he does  like this: `rs = cstmt.getResultSet()`. I get a null pointer exception when I try it that way. I just can't understand why `cstmnt.executeUpdate()` doesn't error out. It would help if I know the store procedure wasn't working, but it atleast returns one record back correctly.

Comment: Can you post your stored procedure? It looks like (based on the exception that you have posted) you are not returning a result set at all, just the output parameters.

Comment: @ahoxha I have added the stored procedure now.

Comment: Your SP is not returning a result set, it is only giving values to the output parameters, that's why `ResultSet rs = cstmt.executeQuery()` throws an exception.

Comment: ... `executeUpdate()` works because it doesn't expect the SP to return a result set, but an `int` which is number of updated records.

Comment: How do I tell the sp to return a result set?

Comment: I'll post the answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify the SP to return a result set, because the `executeQuery()` method expects the SP to return a result set.

Assuming that all other parts of the SP are correct (I could not test it on my PC for various reasons), here's the SP that should work:

```
USE [someDB]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_GetAvatarInfo] 
(
    @idList VARCHAR(MAX)
)
AS 
BEGIN 

DECLARE @idAvatarEvent INT,
        @avatarDisease INT;

SELECT @idAvatarEvent = idEventType
        FROM CCR.dbo.EventType
WHERE codeCancerGroup = 'TCC' AND eventType = 'Avatar';

--Create table to hold all SL ids that are involved in the search
IF (OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#SLList') IS NOT NULL) DROP TABLE #SLList;
CREATE TABLE #SLList
(
        idAlias INT NOT NULL IDENTITY (1,1)
        ,SLNumber VARCHar(100)
)


INSERT INTO #SLList (SLNumber)
SELECT [str]
FROM BST.dbo.fn_parseString(@idList, ',');

SELECT @avatarDisease = ATT.idAttribute
        FROM CCR.dbo.Attribute          ATT
          JOIN CCR.dbo.AttributeContainer ATC ON ATT.idAttributeContainer = ATC.idAttributeContainer
WHERE ATT.attributeName = 'avatarDiseaseGroup'
        AND ATC.containerName = 'Avatar'

  SELECT per.mrn 'PERMRN',
         per.firstName + ' ' + per.lastName 'FULLNAME',
         ali.ccNumberSeq 'CCNUMSEQ', 
         sat.aliasType 'ALIASTYPE`', 
         sl.SLNumber 'SLNUMBER', 
         sst.description 'TISSUETYPE',
         case when pt.preparationType LIKE '%Formalin%' THEN 'FFPE' ELSE pt.preparationType END 'SAMPLESUBTYPE',
         ac.choice 'SUBMITTEDDIAG'
        FROM #SLList sl
                LEFT JOIN DB1.dbo.AliquotAlias sa on sl.SLNumber = sa.alias
                LEFT JOIN DB1.dbo.AliquotAliasType sat on sa.idAliasType = sat.idAliasType
                LEFT JOIN DB1.dbo.VIEW_Aliquot2 ali on sa.idAliquot = ali.idAliquot
                LEFT JOIN DB1.dbo.Sample sam on ali.idSample = sam.id
                LEFT JOIN DB1.dbo.VIEW_SampleSubType sst on sam.codeSampleSubType = sst.codeSampleSubType
                LEFT JOIN DB1.dbo.PreparationType pt on sam.idPreparationType = pt.id
                LEFT JOIN DB1.dbo.BSTCollection col on sam.idBSTCollection = col.idBSTCollection
                LEFT JOIN DB1.dbo.BSTPatient pat on col.idBSTPatient = pat.idBSTPatient
                LEFT JOIN DB2.dbo.Person per on pat.idPerson = per.idPerson
                LEFT JOIN DB3.dbo.Patient cpat on per.idPerson = cpat.idPerson
                LEFT JOIN DB3.dbo.PatientCancerGroup pcg on cpat.idPatient = pcg.idPatient AND pcg.codeCancerGroup = 'TCC'
                LEFT JOIN DB3.dbo.MedicalEvent med on pcg.idPatient = med.idPatient AND pcg.codeCancerGroup = med.codeCancerGroup AND med.idEventType = @idAvatarEvent
                LEFT JOIN DB3.dbo.AttributeValue av on med.idAttributeValueSet = av.idAttributeValueSet AND av.idAttribute = @avatarDisease
                LEFT JOIN DB3.dbo.AttributeChoice ac on av.valueIdAttributeChoice = ac.idAttributeChoice
        ORDER BY per.mrn
END;
```